# store information received from serial and store in a file on raspberry pi

Tags: python, file, raspberry-pi

radio 1 transmitts:

```
outTemp= value
inTemp= value
barometer= value
pressure= value
windSpeed= value
windDir= value
windGust= value
windGustDir= value
outHumidity= value
radiation= value
UV= value
rain= value
/n
```

radio 2 SHOULD receive and store in file called wxdata for read/write

the code to receive on a raspberry pi is:

```
import serial
import time


baud=57600                 #declare baud rate
ser=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0',baud)   #declare serial port/baud rate

target=open( 'wxdata' , 'w+' )     #open the wxdata file

with ser as port, target as outf:  #import serial data to target file
    while 1:
        outf.seek(0)       #seek to index 0 in file wxdata
        outf.write(ser.readline())
        outf.flush()
        time.sleep(1)  #delay one second
```

the information stored in wxdata is not consistant.  It is supposed store only the current transmission, so it overwrites the last one. Any ideas!??

Comment: Is that not the behaviour you want/expect?

Comment: What do you mean by "not consistent"? What are you actually observing?

Comment: @PaulRooney 'w+' doesn't append, it truncates.

Comment: it reads one line only and changes everytime I open wxdata to see what has been wrote

Comment: everytime I open wxdata it should have the most current transmission from radio one in it.  Everything I have tried just gets pieces of the transmission and not the whole list

Comment: the file wxdata needs to be read and writeable